# splitted normalized dataset logistic regression

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression

I was given a dataset that was already splitted into two files, a test data file and a train data file. The data in the both files is normalized.
I was asked to do binomial logistic regression and evaluate the model using some metrics and create a training summary using Spark. I am using python in combination with Spark.

The goal is to develop a Spark application that will first build a classification model using the train dataset and then test it using the test dataset.
Finally, I will execute the Spark application and study the model performance while varying the maximum iterations allowed during training.
I must execute the application with five values of my choice for the number of maximum iterations. For each execution, I need to record at least three
model performance metrics such as area under the ROC curve, accuracy, precision, recall, etc

```
Train: https://pastebin.com/KWsp6jAp
Test: https://pastebin.com/KVYEWZeA
```

I already finished coding but I am confused because the dataset is already splitted.

My questions are:

Do I:

1. need to check both files, train and test for missing values or 0 and
   replace them with NaN (because they are already normalized)?
2. imputer for both files?
3. put in two different single vectors (one for each file) all the features?
4. StandardScaler to scalerize feature column for both vectors?
5. check whether there is an imbalance in the train data and handle it?
6. how to find out which five number of iterations should I run?

I followed this guide here: https://github.com/dhirajprai/SparkML/blob/master/SparkML/logisticregression.ipynb
(the dataset used here seems to have different values/not normalized)

Comment: there are some zeros but almost all values are 0    - what does this mean.

Comment: @thebluephantom it is normalized

Answer (score 0):

This is more a common sense question.

Look at this example http://www.semspirit.com/artificial-intelligence/machine-learning/preparing-the-data/preparing-the-data-in-python/splitting-the-dataset-into-training-and-test-sets/. I just googled and found this although I know from machine learning courses the same I will state. Also, your own reference alludes to the same.

You see from these 2 sources the general approach:

- They do all the manipulations you reference.
- Then they split.

Why your data is delivered as train & test up front is not clear to me as it not that usual.

All the aspects you mention have already been done more than likely - as you state data is normalized.

Normalization is a scaling technique in which values are shifted and re-scaled so that they end up ranging between 0 and 1. It is also known as Min-Max scaling. So you need not do anything about 0(something) values. Some debate on this aspect BTW in some cases.

Step 3 and 6 only required therefore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really don't know why the data is already splitted. It was given that way. Maybe because the course is not machine learning but it's related to Spark. I included both files in pastebin links. I thought it was to help, and skip the split part.

Comment: Ok that was what I thought too. To do every thing twice. But I don't know for the missing values, I mean if there is a record that has 0 to blood pressure column what will happen? Do I have to replace it? or it's correct because of normalization?

Comment: missing values and zero are different things

Comment: ok, so the easy case here is having zeros. But it will be correct to replace them with the mean value? And what will happen? because the data are in two files. I can't have the same mean

Comment: good point indeed, updated answer. they save you time with this approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So because the data is already normalized I should do only 3 and 6? As for the imbalance, I checked the train file and it seems that the target label value=1 has 65% percentage in train and only 35% is 0. Why step 4 is not necessary?

Comment: it was an assumption that they would also do that given normalizing. not all algorithms need this.

Comment: in any event if you want step 4, then only for train, not test